# Elasticsearch_Installation_asking for username and password

Tags: elasticsearch

After installation of Elasticsearch and running the elasticsearch.bat command. I need to check in https:localhost9200.
Here I am getting a prompt asking for username and password.

Is there any default username or password???

Comment: No, there is not any default username and password. Can you add the log message here asking for the credentials?

Comment: @Vaibhav, are you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can Generate a new password using

> /usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-setup-passwords **auto**/**interactive**

**interactive** is where you will have to enter password for all user.

**auto** will just print passwords on the shell.

else

**You can turn off x-pack security in elasticsearch.yml**

Comment: The answer written by @harshit is correct. I just wanted to note you can go to the `config` folder and in `elasticsearch.yml` make `false` security features for xpack or Https instead of the default which is `true` to skip the login or use other solutions mentioned to get the password.

Answer (score 4):

**For Windows:-**

Go to `C:\xampp\htdocs\elasticsearch-8.2.2\bin` folder.

under the above folder or path open the PowerShell terminal.

Now run this command :  `.\elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic .`

**NOTE - don't forget to add dott (.) at the last.**

Then you will see the reset password on the terminal, so now the browser login details will be -

```
username - elastic     // default username
password - new generated token/password
```

See the Screenshot for reference -

[image]

**Read More Here:**

1-> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html#windows-service

2-> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html

Answer (score 2):

**Answer written by @harshit is correct**, Adding more information so that it would be more helpful to the users running ES from code or want more context.

When you run it with source there is default username/password(applicable even in the ES 8.0) as mentioned in the [ES code contribution guide](https://github.com/amitmbm/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-to-the-elasticsearch-codebase) and `elastic` is the default username and `password` is the default password.

Note that, **from ES 8.0 even in Basic and trial ES version** `x-pack security` is enabled by default, and it was disabled before ES 8.0. So if you want to disable it you need to add below setting to your `elasticsearch.yml` and restart ES.(Not recommended though)

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Also, `elastic` is a reserved username in Elasticsearch, and when you install ES from an archive on *nix based system, its password is not generated due to [known issue](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/release-notes-8.0.0.html#known-issues-8.0.0), but if you running it on Docker or on Windows it would be generated and password will be printed in the cluster logs as explained in [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html), where ES advises to store it in secure location.

Comment: How to do this in windows ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the elasticsearch 8 documentation [auto/interactive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-passwords.html) is depricated.
Instead we will be using the following command for setting the elasticsearch password.

```
elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic --interactive
```

[image]